# Use Python reserved words in an XML File

Tags: python, xml, reserved-words

I'm currently trying to use python's (3.6) xml.etree.ElementTree commands to write an xml file. Some of the Elements and Subelements I need to write must have "id" and "map" fields, which are reserved python words.

My problem is contained in the following line of code:

`ET.SubElement(messages,'trigger',thing='1',bob='a', max='5')`

But "max" is a function and I can't use it. Is there a character I can place there to allow me to write this field as I desire? Or some sort of known workaround?

EDIT: I am aware that an '_' stops the python from processing the word, but unfortunately this underscore will show up in my file...so I am trying to see if there is an 'invisible' option for the file I will later be writing.

Thanks much!

Comment: Try`ET.SubElement(messages,'trigger', {'thing': '1', 'bob': 'a', 'max': '5'})`.

Answer (score 0):

Python functions are no problem in the left side of a keyword expression:

```
>>> def abc(**kwargs):
    print kwargs
>>> abc(id=2)
{'id': 2}
>>>
```

id, map, int, float, str, repr, etc. are built in symbols, not reserved words. You may use them like any other bunch of letters, but assigning it another value replaces the built in symbol:

```
>>> int(2.5)
2
>>> int = "5"
>>> int(2.5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    int(2.5)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Notice how the first line is entirely legal, but will trigger a warning if you have a good IDE like pycharm.

If you want to send a actual reserved word to a function, like print, None, yield, or try, you can use the double star ** to convert a dictionary into keyword arguments, for example:

```
>>> abc(**{"print":2, "None":3})
{'print': 2, 'None': 3}
```

I hope this answers your question!